# UITableViewCellStateMask strange value in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.0.1. I've got an iOS7 app that has a custom tableViewCell that uses:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

//...code
}
```

Now, when I place the cell in edit mode in my viewController, the value of "state" is some bizarre new value, "2147483649"

Did something change in the stateMask value, or in how you place a cell in edit mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, only with iOS8 (didn't have this problem on iOS 7.1.1)I noticed that this happens when my tableView is implementing its dataSource delegate method's for reordering cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

When I delete these methods from my tableView's delegate class, I got the correct state from UITableViewCell's     [willTransitionToState:]     method.

I submitted a bug to apple, bug's number is 18536460, will add a link when available

Comment: Apple support insisted that I would send them a testApp to demonstrate the problem... well I did. Not surprisingly their response was that there is no bug, and I should use the '&' operator to check the value returned from [willTransitionToState:] rather than the '==' operator. I told them that I am doing neither, I just print the UITableViewCellStateMask state to console. Yet again they referred me to their prior response... . Well I checked this bug a few days later, it seems to work mysteriously OK now.